# Questions about Multimedia Systems

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm taking a module on my Computer Science masters degree called "Multimedia Systems" and I would really like to get some help with it. The problem is I'm not sure where to ask questions.  Below are the topics which it includes.  I am VERY sorry for the messy pasting job but it would take to look to format this - hopefully you can forgive me and just try to spot the general gist of it.  The topics are broadly split into multimedia compression and transmission over a network.  Where would I ask questions?

- Discrete Cosine Transform Coefficient Coding Audio CodingAnalogue and digital form:
- Sample rate, bits/sample, nyquist rate, CD audio
  Compression techniques:
- PCM, ADPCM, LPC, GSM/CELP, MP3/AAC VideoTV Standards:
- Interlacing vs progressive scan, PAL, NTSC, SECAM
  Video digitisation
  Raw Image Representation:
- RGB, YUV411, YUV422, Indexed color vs true colour
  Image Compression:
- GIF, JPEG, Motion JPEG:
  Video Compression:
- Motion estimation
- Motion compensation
  Video Compression Schemes:
- H.261, H.263
- MPEG 1, MPEG 2, MPEG 4
  Video Adaptation:
- Sender-side adaptation, buffering, VBR->CBR conversion System StreamsMPEG program and transport streams
  H.221 framing (for ISDN)
  IP-based transport:
- packet loss
- TCP vs UDP
- Application-level framing
- RTP
- H.261 as example of payload format
- DCCP
  Audio/Video synchronization
- RTCP
- MPEG system stream SignallingH.323
  SIP and SDP
  RTSP
  Megaco OS IssuesBuffering
  Scheduling Describing Network TrafficTraffic patterns
  Application requirements
  QoS parameters and descritions Congestion control and Resource ManagementTCP congestion control
  Real-time traffic congestion control
  Queue management:
- Random Early Detection + other AQM
- Explicit Congection Notification (ECN)
- Scheduling mechanisms (FQ, WFQ) Enhanced Quality of ServiceIntserv
  Resource reSerVation Protocol (RSVP)
  Diffserv IP MulticastService Model
  Layered transmission
  Multicast congestion control Digital rights managementLegal issues
  Watermarking

Comment: goto http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're talking about [Audio and Video Processing](https://video.stackexchange.com/) and we have a site for that, but they're more for advanced questions on that topic; I can't really tell if you're in that category.

If you're doing this stuff programmatically you should ask on Stack Overflow of course or if it's simpler stuff like "how do I install X program" or "how do I convert X files to Y" it's better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Basically it depends if you're *producing* multimedia (probably AVP), listening to/converting them (Super User) or operating on multimedia programmatically (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Hi Ben - thanks for fast reply.  There isn't any programming - the most difficult parts are the computer networking parts to be honest - do you know if there is a forum for that?  Also, is Super User meant for advanced users?  Because this stuff is mostly concerned with things like huffman encoding, fourier transforming matrices of values representing pixels etc - it's quite technical but not pure enough to put in a computer science forum - thanks for help!

Comment: @user1058210 networking in what sense? [su] accepts consumer/end user networking questions or [sf] accepts system-administrator type networking questions. There's also the [dsp.se] site: 
Signal Processing - Stack Exchange is for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your professor and TAs. The entire network frowns on homework questions. This isn't the place to go for general information, and homework questions often place artificial constraints on the answers that make them difficult or inappropriate to answer.